# Is it possible to ecrypt and decrypt files on Amazon S3 bucket from my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am building an application that will upload files to Amazon's S3 bucket. I am looking at the possibility where I can send a request to Amazon's server to encrypt a file using the key and algorithm I will provide.

Comment: Have you looked into AWS KMS (Key Management Service)? Encrypting S3 objects is almost trivial with KMS. You can provide your own key using SSE-C https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-s3.html

Comment: Thank you so much...
After encrypting the file on Amazon's server using a personal key, can I download the encrypted file and decrypt it on my local device? Let's say an Android app.

Answer (score 1):

S3 supports server side encryption. It also integrates with KMS, which lets you provide a custom key (customer master key) for signing S3 objects (files). Have a look at the [relevant docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/serv-side-encryption.html) and  have a look at the limits and costs associated with it.